# How to take a value from row 1, row 2, row 3 in column 3 using DBGrid?

Tags: mysql, delphi, pascal, dbgrid

In Delphi, I have a component:

```
dbgridsimpipa: Tdbgrid,
DSpipa: Tdatasource,
Qpipa: Tquery,
btnViewdata: tbutton
btnRecNumber: tbutton.
```

I search the table with this code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnViewDataClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  st,st4,y0,y1,y2: string;
begin
  st:='5';
  grid2.Enabled := True;
  st5 := 'SELECT tblRekapROT.CY2IDR, tblRekapROT.Produk, tblRekapROT.Total,         tblRekapROT.ARRWL, tblRekapROT.ARBYL, tblRekapROT.Status '+
  'FROM tblRekapROT '+
  'WHERE ((tblRekapROT.Status Like  ''%'+st+'%''))';
   Qpipa.Close;
   Qpipa.SQL.Clear;
   Qpipa.SQL.Add(st5);
   Qpipa.Open;
   label22.Caption:= dbgridsimpipa.Fields[0].AsString;
end;
```

Then I count the records in `DBGrid` with :

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnRecNumberClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vCount: Integer;
  vBookmark: TBookmark;
begin
  vCount := 0;

  with DBGridSimPipa.DataSource.DataSet do
  begin    
    vBookmark := GetBookmark;
    First;  // move to the first record

    while not EoF do
    begin
      vCount := vCount + 1;      
      Next;                   // move to next record
    end;

    GotoBookmark(vBookmark);
    FreeBookmark(vBookmark);
  end;  
  ShowMessage('We found ' + IntToStr(vCount) + ' records');
end;
```

How do I get the value of rows in `DBGrid` in one column? Maybe like this:

```
//label1.Caption:= dbgridsimpipa.DataSource.DataSet.First          //record vtotal row 1

   //label2.Caption:= dbgridsimpipa.DataSource.DataSet.second         //record vtotal row 2
   //label3.Caption:= dbgridsimpipa.DataSource.DataSet.third           //record vtotal row 3
```

[This a screenshot of my program.](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CABurI5VAAAyj0H.jpg:large)

Answer (score 2):

First of all welcome to StackOverflow.

You have some misunderstanding about how dataset works. First of all if you want to know how many rows you found you can just call the RecordCound property:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnRecNumberClick(Sender: TObject);
begin      
  ShowMessage('We found ' + IntToStr(DBGridSimPipa.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount) + ' records');
end;
```

If you want to Access the first row in a Dataset you can call `First` but there are no `Second` or `Third` property so there you'll have to ude the property `RecordNo`

`DataSet.First` is the same as `Dataset.RecordNo := 0`

The second row you get by calling  `Dataset.RecordNo := 1` etc.

THen you wanted to put then content of a row into a label. There are no build in way of doing that, so you'll have to write you own function to to this.

```
function DataRowToString(const aDataset: TDataSet; aRecNo: Integer): String;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  aDataset.RecNo := aRecNo;
  Result := '';
  for i := 0 to aDataset.FieldCount - 1 do
    Result := Result + aDataset.Fields[i].AsString + ' ';

  Result := Trim(Result);
end;
```

Finally we just need to call the newly created function:

```
label1.Caption:= DataRowToString(dbgridsimpipa.DataSource.DataSet, 0); //record vtotal row 1
label2.Caption:= DataRowToString(dbgridsimpipa.DataSource.DataSet, 1); //record vtotal row 2
label3.Caption:= DataRowToString(dbgridsimpipa.DataSource.DataSet, 2);//record vtotal row 3
```

Comment: i have do that,,, but any error .how to put: function DataRowToString(const aDataset: TDataSet; aRecNo: Integer): String; in header??

Comment: Yuo mean make it a Method?